# How to abort an HTTP post without reading its full contents (.NET REST service)

Tags: .net, wcf, rest, post, httpwebrequest

I have created a self-hosted .NET service that accepts binary uploads.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IBinaryService
{

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "up/file/{fileName}/{hash}")]

    void FileUpload(string fileName, string hash, Stream fileStream);
```

When it receives a file, it first checks whether that file is already on the system, otherwise it streams the file from the client and saves it:

```
    public void FileUpload(string fileName, string hash, Stream fileStream)
    {
        string filebasedir = basedir + @"file\"; //" 
        if (File.Exists(filebasedir + hash))
        {

            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = 
                                   System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Conflict;
            return;
        }

        using(var fileToupload = new FileStream(
                string.Concat(filebasedir, hash),
                FileMode.Create))
                {
                fileStream.CopyTo(fileToupload);
                }
```

If I step through the code, I can see that the file content is not streamed until AFTER the server has read the parameters and decided whether there is a conflict. I just need to somehow force the server to not read the full contents (which could be many megabytes). Exiting the method early using 'return' does not do this unfortunately.

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried closing the stream before returning with `fileStream.Close();`?

Comment: Thanks. Just tried it. Does not work.

Comment: This streams , I mean fileStream argument shouldn't be closed manually, WCF REST infrastructure closes it.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand the issue you are facing correctly..

Client calls the method

```
void FileUpload(string fileName, string hash, Stream fileStream);
```

And as soon as it calls that function, it starts uploading the file to the server.
You want to avoid or interrupt the file upload, if file already exists on the server.

Why don't you split your method in to two, one method will check if file already exists on the server (it will have only two arguments filename and hash, don't pass the filestream ), and return true or false, and if it doesn't exist then call the second method with filestream parameter.

That way it should solve your problem.

Comment: This approach creates a race condition where two (or more) clients can simultaneously check that a file doesn't exist before all uploading it.  Agree that it makes things less bad though and its very easy to implement.

Comment: Yeah, it crossed my mind to break it up into two operations. Was hoping I just had to change a line of code to get WCF to cooperate, but I guess that's not a possibility based on the divergence of answers. Cheers

Comment: @simonc thanks, I did not thought about race condition, what do you suggest for taking care of race condition, some thread synchronization, locks or critical region?

Answer (score 0):

The built in functionality in the framework (the server side fileupload control) does not provide a finer level of granularity to process the data received in chunks during the upload process. It simply buffers all the data in memory until it gets to the end of the file or encounters an error condition.

So your only options are to either:

1) Do it yourself by writer a binary file upload handler (httpHandler). Not impossible, but not as trivial as it might sound at first glance. This will involve determining request encoding methods and using the proper techniques for possible variations to properly decode the encoded binary data in the stream.

2) A much easier solution would be to just use one of the existing commercial controls which implements this functionality for you and exposes events you can use to drive your own code. For example, take a look at [ABCUpload.NET](http://www.websupergoo.com/abcupload.net-1.htm) as one example. Another is [PowUpload](http://www.element-it.com/asp-net-component/http-upload-control.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

Possible, just return response with error code and do not stream file

Comment: How? that's what I'm trying to accomplish. See my code. The WCF service streams the file even if I return immediately after setting an error code "conflict".

Comment: Try throw exception instead of return, like 
throw new WebFaultException(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Conflict);

Comment: No luck. That has the same result :(

Comment: Why you think that WCF streams file even if return or throw exception? Sure, that in Stream parameter first chunk of data is transferred to service, but after error or immediate return rest part of file, other chunk wouldn't be transferred to server. And size of the first chunk depends from maxBufferSize config

Comment: WebHttpBinding b = new WebHttpBinding();
            b.MaxBufferSize = 256*1024;
            b.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647;
            b.TransferMode = TransferMode.Streamed;

Comment: Those are my binding options. The full data is streamed after the return/exception. I can see the network traffic entering the server. Is there something that needs to be done on the client as well? Thanks!

Comment: I have the same options in binding. All my samples with streaming using WCF 4 REST, ASP.NET WebAPI (WCF WebAPI) are working perfectly. Main difference with yours, that they aren't self hosted and hosting on IIS. May be problem in self hosted app, do not know exactly. 

But anyway, I know workaround for you. It's using chunk-by-chunk uploading techniques. For example, chunks could have size of 200Kb. Chunk-by-chunk uploading could give you a full control over byte stream. 

Also as you are using self hosted, posting client code here would be worth.

Comment: I will try to move it to IIS hosting and if that changes the result, I will come back and accept your answer. Thanks for the help. Breaking down the upload into multiple calls would work, and what others were suggesting, but was hoping I did not have to go that route.

Answer (score -2):

You can use `OperationContext.Current.RequestContext.Abort()` method.

Comment: All right, it let server not to receive full content from client.

Comment: If I understand, OP needs abort http request from client _on server side, from server code_, in his `FileUpload` method. If method just doesn't read stream, client will send this stream, because underlying TCP connection stay opened for some time. And if server aborts client's request, TCP connection will be closed, and client will got exception and won't send whole stream. btw, sorry for my english, if there are any mistakes.